# Howt to add the antisymmetric part of the data (y(-x) = -y(x)) using the data in the positive x axis in tikzplot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a data which is antisymmetric that I want to draw using tikzplot. I want to add the antisymmetric part of the data (y(-x) = -y(x)) using the data in the positive x axis.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some code to start with, preferably a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the problem you're stuck with. Otherwise, it might be difficult to come up with an answer that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the blue curve represents the original function y(x), and the red curve represents the antisymmetric part y(-x) = -y(x). The `domain` option specifies the range of x-values you want to plot, and you can adjust it based on your dataset.

This method allows you to plot only the positive side of the x-axis and automatically generate the antisymmetric part by reflecting the curve.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    axis lines=middle,
    domain=0:5, % adjust the domain as needed
    samples=100,
    legend pos=outer north east,
  ]

  % Define your function y(x)
  \addplot[blue, mark=none, domain=0:5] {sin(deg(x))};

  % Define the antisymmetric part y(-x) = -y(x)
  \addplot[red, mark=none, domain=0:5] {-sin(deg(x))};

  \legend{$y(x)$, $y(-x)$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Sebastiano,. Thanks for your answer. But, I don`t have a function. I just hava a data for positive x. I want to plot the negative values of x using the data in positive x axis. For negative x, I want to plot -y(x).

Comment: I found the answer using table[
        x expr=-{\thisrrow{0}},
        y expr=-{\thisrow{1}}
        ] {\datatable}; You need to use \pgfplotstableread

Comment: @MehmetA.Guler But is neccesary that I use \pgfplotstableread?

Comment: Yes it it necessary to use \pgfplotstableread Sebastano